# How to set a widget as a button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sidebar

I set two widgets in a Stack(), the one in the back is a sidebar and the one in the front is my main page.
When I click on the menu button from the main page, the main page gets shifted to the right and then the user can see the sidebar.

[image]

Now the problem is when the sidebar gets displyed i'm obliged to click exactly on the menu button to go back to the main page.
What i want to do is just to click anywhere in the main page to hide the sidebar.
I mean that i want to set the whole main page as a button when the sidebar is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by wrapping the main page with InkWell() and I added this to the onTap property"

```
      InkWell(
        onTap: isSidebarCollapsed ? () {
          setState(() {
            isSidebarCollapsed = false;
          });
        } : null,
        child: Container(...)
      )
```

Note that isSidebarCollapsed is the variable that determines if the menu is displayed or not.

Explaination of the code:
If the sidebar is collapsed (is displayed) then the onTap property returns a function where I set the variable isSidebarCollapsed to false (to say that the sidebar is gonna be hidden).
Else it returns **null**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)

```
     InkWell(
        onTap: (){
         /// do something
        },
        child: Text('data')  /// your widget,
      ),
```

You can also use [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Comment: Don't forget that the main page has also its own buttons, so if I do what you said, I'll not be able to click on its other buttons, it means that I'll have only a page with one big.
Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: You will able to click on other button as well. Please try this and Let me know if I can help with anything.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, please read the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you want to make anything tappable you can just wrap the widget with GestureDetector